# Can't Understand mHandler.obtainMessage() in Android Bluetooth sample

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, handler, inputstream

I'm Working on Bluetooth rfcomm connection. There's a line in Android Sample that I can't understand and unfortunately I couldn't find a good answer in other questions and resources.

Here is the whole code:

```
public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
```

I can't Understand this line:

```
 // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);    
// Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                                .sendToTarget();
```

`mHandler` is not defined in this code and also `MESSAGE_READ`

I can't understand what does `bytes` do?

I think and as mentioned in comment it sends the received Bytes to the Activity which I set as my Main Activity. Can I make a `Static TextView` in my main Activity instead of sendToTarget() to show the received message?

Comment: mHandler is probably an instance variable, declared somewhere in your class. MESSAGE_READ is probably a constant, defined in the class or via a static import.

Answer (score 7):

The main goal of `Handler` is to provide interface between producer and consumer thread, here, between UI thread and worker thread. Implementation of `Handler` goes into consumer thread.

In your case, you want to communicate `MESSAGE_READ` between threads.

Without handler you can do nothing out of your main Activity Thread.

Therefore, look for `mHandler` initiation into main Activity.

The default handler init should be like:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
 @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
 /**/
  }
};
```

If you use Eclipse,  click on your Project -> Ctrl+H -> File Search -> "Handler".

Or in Notepad++ -> Serch -> Find in files ....

**[EDIT]**

```
final int MESSAGE_READ = 9999; // its only identifier to tell to handler what to do with data you passed through.  

// Handler in DataTransferActivity
public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
  switch (msg.what) {
    case SOCKET_CONNECTED: {
      mBluetoothConnection = (ConnectionThread) msg.obj;
      if (!mServerMode)
        mBluetoothConnection.write("this is a message".getBytes());
      break;
    }
    case DATA_RECEIVED: {
      data = (String) msg.obj;
      tv.setText(data);
      if (mServerMode)
       mBluetoothConnection.write(data.getBytes());
     }
     case MESSAGE_READ:
      // your code goes here
```

I'm sure you must implement something like:

```
new ConnectionThread(mBluetoothSocket, mHandler);
```

sources i found [here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2010/CMSC498G/CMSC498G/Slides_files/Bluetooth.pptx&ei=PNj8UdmlGND3sgaduoBw&usg=AFQjCNFIR2zoim9sk9n90K3fV4YygszXag&sig2=medFXiEMJijzEGGijTQRCA&bvm=bv.50165853,d.Yms)

Comment: Thanks, How about Bytes? What does it do?

Comment: Hmm, Think I should Write whole code here. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Well, no one will read full your code, 1st read what is Handler in Android,

Comment: @MaximShoustin A query, if the connection is successful with bluetooth device, as you can execute the function that reads the data sent from the Bluetooth device to the application? I have everything set up but I can not get what they send my bluetooth device

Comment: @sioesi would suggest grabbing the full tutorial/sample here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat this way you can see how all the parts are connected and have a working sample to start with (I'm doing the same today, I started on this path yesterday trying to make a bluetooth remote for my DIY electric skateboard.... I broke the last remote taking it apart and wiring it wrong)